# Handler doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

first of all excuse me if my title doesn't describe my question very well but i couldn't find a better one .

there is a simple stopWatch app that has three button start,stop,reset and a textview to display time . app has just one activity like this:

```
public class StopwatchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private int mNumberOfSeconds = 0;
private boolean mRunning = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stopwatch);
    //if if uncomment this runner method and delete the runner inside onClickStart everything will work find 
    //runner()

}

public void onClickStart(View view){
    mRunning = true;
    runner();
}

public void onClickStop(View view){
    mRunning = false;
}

public void onClickReset(View view){
    mRunning = false;
    mNumberOfSeconds = 0;

}

public void runner(){
    final TextView timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int hours = mNumberOfSeconds/3600;
            int minutes = (mNumberOfSeconds%3600)/60;
            int second = mNumberOfSeconds%60;
            String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d" , hours , minutes , second );
            timeView.setText(time);
            if (mRunning){
                mNumberOfSeconds++;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this , 1000);
        }
    });

}
}
```

my problem is when i comment the runner() in onClickStart method and put it in the onCreate method everything is ok . but when i change the code like above the code is still running but after i press stop button and then press start again the second will increment by 4 or 5 very fast. 
can anyone explain me what is the difference between this two modes?

Comment: You aren't killing the first runner, so when you re-start the timer, a second runner is created. As you only test for the value of mRunning, the first runner begins to clock up again as well as the second.

Comment: @Nick why when i put runner() inside the onCreate code will work find . i think it's the same scenario

Comment: Because onCreate only gets executed once, so you only ever start one instance of the runner.

Comment: @Nick thank you . seems correct . but have you any idea for my code to work correct in this way too ?

Comment: If it works just starting up one instance in onCreate why do you need to change it?

Comment: @nick i just want to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare your handler globally

```
public void runner(){
    timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time_view);
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int hours = mNumberOfSeconds/3600;
            int minutes = (mNumberOfSeconds%3600)/60;
            int second = mNumberOfSeconds%60;
            String time = String.format("%d:%02d:%02d" , hours , minutes , second );
            timeView.setText(time);
            if (mRunning){
                mNumberOfSeconds++;
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this , 1000);
        }
    }
    handler.post(runnable);

}
```

in button function

```
public void onClickStart(View view){
    if(handler != null) {
        //restart the handler to avoid duplicate runnable 
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);//or this handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }
    mRunning = true;
    runner();
}

public void onClickStop(View view){
    mRunning = false;
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable); // this will stop the handler from working
}
```

Comment: when i want to run this code and after the app get started . after pressing start button a null pointer exception will throw

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Handler.removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference

Comment: i fixed it . just instantiate Handler when declaring it . thank you